# Recursive query using JPA to get employee hierarchy

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, recursive-query

I am trying to find a way to get the employee hierarchy in an organization using JPA and Spring boot.

The problem is similar to the following link
[Similar Data Model](https://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-self-join-annotations-one-to-many-mapping/)

If A reports to B and B reports to C and C reports to D,

For employee B i need the output to be B->C->D.

The following the Recursive query in Mysql

```
WITH RECURSIVE Employee_path(id,Name,bid) AS(
SELECT id,Name,bid
FROM Employee
WHERE id = 1005
UNION ALL
SELECT e.id,e.Name,e.bid
FROM Employee_path AS cp JOIN Employee AS e
ON cp.bid = e.id
)
SELECT * FROM Employee_path ORDER by bid ASC;
```

Since I am new to JPA I am unable to get the solution in an optimised way(I am not getting how to approach this problem)

I just added a recursive way of getting it in an optimised way.

PFL for the repo 
[For my git repo](https://github.com/anjandv/Register)

Consider following example as MySQL snapshot

```
id  name bid
1   A     0
2   B     1
3   C     2
4   D     1
```

I want to get the Reporting manager line for person C
Which should return string C->B->A

Comment: Can you show your data and expected output more clearly

Comment: Thank you.I have updated the question hope that helps.